# Разбить число и вывести из функции результат избежав двухмерного массива

Tags: python, массивы

Задача создать функцию, которая разбивает любое число на однозначные числа.

Вроде получилось, но не могу догнать, как избежать двухмерного массива в итоге в переменной `z` и вывести из функции по нормальному, чтобы потом было проще с этими числами работать.
Обе функции должны остаться для дальнейшего кода, т.е. razbiv передает в переменную z из persistence результат.

Мой код:

```
def persistence(n):
    z = []
    def razbiv(n):
        x = [int(a) for a in str(n)]
        c = z.append(x)
    razbiv(n)

    return print(z)
persistence(39)
```

Выдает:

> [[3, 9]]

---

В допоолнение подскажите, как можно вообще избежать массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей функции переменная `x` уже принимает список, который вам необходим, а далее вы берете и методом .append добавляете его в другой пустой список `z`, тем самым создавая вложенный список, от которого и пытаетесь избавиться. Для вашей задачи будет достаточно такой функции:

```
def persistence(n):
  lst = [int(i) for i in str(n)]
  return lst
```

Данная функция принимает на вход число (*например 467*), а на выходе возвращает готовый список `[4, 6, 7]`, который вы и можете использовать дальше в своем коде. Как пример, можете присвоить его переменной и далее работать уже с ней:

```
z = persistence(input('Введи любое число: '))

print(z)
```

Вывод:

> Введи любое число: 16546
>
> [1, 6, 5, 4, 6]

Если вам прям так хочется явно объявить переменную `z`, то выносите делайте ее глобальной, объявив ее вне функции, а внутри функции уже переписывайте ее:

```
z = []

def persistence(n):
  global z
  z = [int(i) for i in str(n)]
  return z

persistence(123)

print(z)
```

Вывод:

> [1, 2, 3]

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо за замечание, дополнил свой ответ

Comment: не правильно сформулировал вопрос, извиняюсь... функции razbiv и persistence нужны обе для дальнейшего кода, проблема не в том чтоб запринтить, а в том чтоб завести результат в переменную z без двухмерного массива.

Comment: @joynik, дополнил свой ответ

Comment: Не называйте свои переменные встроенными штуками питона, например `list`

Comment: global -точно... идеально. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

*z* Уже является массивом. Следовательно вызвав функцию **append** ты добавляешь в массив *z* переменную *x*, которая в свою очередь тоже массив, созданным с помощью list comprehension.

```
def persistence(n):
    x = [int(a) for a in str(n)]
    return print(x)
persistence(39)
```

Comment: не правильно сформулировал вопрос, извиняюсь... функции razbiv и persistence нужны обе для дальнейшего кода, проблема не в том чтоб запринтить, а в том чтоб завести результат в переменную z без двухмерного массива.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще это обычно как-то так делается:

```
def razbiv(n):
    return list(map(int, str(n)))

def persistence(n):
    z = razbiv(n)
    return print(z)

persistence(39)
```

Вывод:

```
[3, 9]
```

Но учтите, что фактически `persistence` у вас возвращает `None`.